# How can you create a contract within a contract and pass the value / payable amount?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, constructor

I want to create another contract in a contract function call and pass the associated ether into that new contract.  Seems like it makes sense to want to do but...

Why doesn't this work?

```
contract B {
    uint x;
    function B(uint a) payable {
        x = a;
    }
}


contract A {
    function createAndPassAmount(uint arg, uint amount) payable {
        B newD = new B.value(amount)(arg);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You need parentheses around `new B` (see below):

```
contract A {
    function createAndPassAmount(uint arg, uint amount) payable {
        B newD = (new B).value(amount)(arg);
    }
}
```